# Ubuntu on RPI starts killing processes when RAM is filled up by cache

Tags: ubuntu, memory

I am running a Raspberry PI with Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1042-raspi2 armv7l) and when I eg. watch a video via Samba, it gets cached and fills up my RAM with cached data.

This will look like this:

```
user@rpi:~$ free -h -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           920M         57M        133M        980K        729M        828M
Swap:          1.8G         29M        1.8G
```

So as far as I understand this, it shouldn't be a bad thing since Ubuntu will see that part of RAM as used but available. So when another process actually needs it, it will be made available.

But when the cache reaches my RAM limit the following will happen:

```
Feb  8 19:08:36 rpi kernel: [160789.617128] Out of memory: Kill process 29171 (myprocess) score 40 or sacrifice child
Feb  8 19:06:08 rpi kernel: [160641.803753] Killed process 29072 (myprocess) total-vm:170312kB, anon-rss:63196kB, file-rss:43628kB
```

Can someone explain to me why this happens and how I can avoid this?
Right now my only temporary solution is to clear the cache manually:

```
sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

PS: I know I shouldn't use Swap on a RPI with a flash drive, it was a temporary test for this issue which didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You have plenty of free RAM. [The cache won't be getting in the way](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/) Linux will give it up as required. You are most likely seeing [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1655842), try downgrading the kernel to an earlier version.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed the same problem with plain Ubuntu on my desktop system. 
Ubuntu 16.04 seems to specifically block cache and it can't be freed by `echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`.

Have you tried switching to a different flavor? In my experience, the cache problem was better e.g. in Lubuntu, you can also try Xubuntu. They generally use less memory.

In general, for a low memory environment such as the Raspi, you'll want to use special software, such as the [Pixel Desktop](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-pixel/).